# Nested ul not working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, list, nested, html-lists

My nested ul renders fine in firefox, chrome and safari, but not in IE. It stops displaying inline immediately after the "answers" link. All links turn blue as well and are stacked vertically.

```
<ul id="headernav">
    <li><a href="donate.php">Donate</a></li>
    <li><a href="answers.php">Answers</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="initiatives.php">Initiatives</a></li>
    </li>
    </ul>
    <li><a style="width:8.5em;" href="news.php"><span class="current">News & Events</span> </a></li>
    <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a>
    <ul class="linkarrow">
        <li><a href="leadership.php">Leadership</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

#headernav {
    width: 555px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align:center;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

#headernav li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;

}

#headernav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width:6em;
    height:35px;
    color:#2e2d2d;
    padding:0.2em 0.6em;
    padding-top:20px;
    margin-left:3px;
    font-size:14px;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    font-weight:400;

}

/*drop down styles*/

#headernav li ul {
    display:none;
}

#headernav li ul {
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:0;
    width:6em;
    font-size:14px;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    font-weight:500;
    height:30px;
    padding-left:10px;



}

#headernav ul li a {
    display:block;
    background:transparent;
    padding:0.3em 0.6em;
    width:6em;
}
```

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your first nested ul. You are closing the containing "li" before the "ul".

This

```
<ul id="headernav">
    <li><a href="donate.php">Donate</a></li>
    <li><a href="answers.php">Answers</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="initiatives.php">Initiatives</a></li>
    </li>
    </ul>
    <li>
    //snap
```

becomes

```
<ul id="headernav">
    <li><a href="donate.php">Donate</a></li>
    <li><a href="answers.php">Answers</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="initiatives.php">Initiatives</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
```

Comment: Thank you! That was the issue.